# How to use a java string method to return a selected amount of characters?

Tags: java, python

I am trying to figure out how to return a selected amount of characters in my java string.
In Python, it is just like

```
randomVar = "hello"
print(randomVar[1:])
```

and the output would be "ello".

How do I do the same thing in java?
Thank you!

Comment: `str.substring(1);`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Java equivalent to Python's Easy String Splicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307761/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-pythons-easy-string-splicing)

Comment: That works fine! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

```
String a = "hello";
System.out.println(a.substring(1, a.length());
```

Comment: This is correct but misleading; just `a.substring(1)` does the job (the 1-arg substring version implies 'to the end', which is what a.length() also does, so the code in this answer is needlessly long.

Comment: I considered that but I thought it would be better to show the overloaded version since he would get more context of how it was used.